# How to append multiple fractions to a list an take their product?

Tags: java

As Java newbie, I have constructed the following simple class `Fraction` with a method `multiply`:

```
public class Fraction{

    private int numerator, denominator;

    public Fraction(){}

    public Fraction(int numerator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        denominator = 1;
    }

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    public void multiply(Fraction m) {
        numerator = m.numerator * numerator;
        denominator = m.denominator * denominator;
    }

    public void printFraction(){
        System.out.println(numerator + "/" + denominator);
    }

}
```

And a second class which runs the method in question on some values:
I would like to assign random values to both numerator and denominator ranging between 1 - 5 and put the corresponding fraction to a list before multiplying them. I just struggle to implement the part where I put them to list and take their product. Not sure how that is possible with fractions:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.* ;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fraction first = new Fraction(10, 2);
        Fraction second = new Fraction(4, 2);
        first.multiply(second);
        first.printFraction();

        Random random = new Random();
        List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            int num = 1 + random.nextInt(5);
            int denum = 1 + random.nextInt(5);
            Fraction first = new Fraction(num, denum);
            int num2 = 1 + random.nextInt(5);
            int denum2 = 1 + random.nextInt(5);
            Fraction second = new Fraction(num2, denum2);
            listOfIntegers.add(first,second);
        }

        listOfIntegers.stream().reduce(1, (first, second) -> first * second)

    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like you want to be working with a `List<Fraction>` instead of a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Oh, thx, but I suppose the loop will still not work properly!

Comment: @Googme: Because when you tried it, something went wrong?

Comment: and use `first.multiply(second)`, not `first * second`

Comment: Hi @ScottHunter, yes  listOfIntegers.add(first,second) requires int not Fraction according to the error message

Comment: You'll want to pass a single `Fraction` object to `list.add(...)` instead of two integers.

Comment: Hi @Jesper, I assumed that, initially I had two for loop each filling iup two list. Reason for that is that I dont understand how to pass a single fraction if there are two of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first want to create a list of Fractions and add them to your list like this

```
    List<Fraction> listOfFractions = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        int num = 1 + random.nextInt(5);
        int denum = 1 + random.nextInt(5);
        Fraction fractionObj = new Fraction(num, denum);
        listOfFractions.add(fractionObj); //add the object to your list
    }
```

Now that you have your fractions created in your list you can loop through the list again and multiply each fraction in the list with one created at random like so

```
for(int i = 0; i < listOfFractions.size(); i++)
{
    int num = 1 + random.nextInt(5);
    int denum = 1 + random.nextInt(5);
    Fraction fraction1 = new Fraction(num, denum); //fraction 1
    Fraction fraction2 = listOfFractions.get(i); //grab the previously created fraction
    System.out.println("Multiplying Fraction 1");
    fraction1.printFraction();
    System.out.println("By Fraction 2");
    fraction2.printFraction();
    System.out.println("Gives us the following fraction");
    fraction1.multiply(fraction2); //multiply the two fractions
    fraction1.printFraction();
}
```

Comment: why aren't you just Iterating the fractions? You aren't using the index at all.

`for(Fraction fraction:fractions)`